# Can $Ae^{-bt^2}\sin(kx-\omega t)$ be considered a wave?

Tags: waves, differential-equations

The damped wave PDE can have an exponential term, but the argument for the exponential term cannot be quadratic, AFAIK.

$Ae^{-bt^2}\sin(kx-\omega t)$

So this isn't a solution for the damped wave PDE. However it looks quite a lot like a traveling wave.

So my question was, is this a wave? What wave PDE does it solve?

Thanks.

Comment: Just differentiate it in time and space once, twice, ..., and see what you get...

Comment: The damped PDE, if solved with separation of variables is linear in its time equation. It can't be what I have. I can't google PDE's that's why I asked here. So what PDE does it satisfy (not just the structure, which I can find out, but its name and how it relates to the wave PDE, e.g. what its several terms mean physically)? Its not a bad question to ask, I can obviously do what you mention, I just wanted a little more information on this situation... Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Chances are that it won't be a PDE with a name.  If it hasn't been associated with a specific physics model its unlikely that its been studied.

Comment: Define a wave. For the purposes of introductory treatments I use *"a traveling disturbance"*. Does that represent a disturbance? Does it travel?

Comment: Yes, it does. My question was more related to whatever the theory of PDEs had to say about this. Perhaps I should've asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of wave is "obey wave equation", then it's not a wave.

If your definition of wave is "a travelling disturbance, not caring whether it's possibly attenuated synchronously with a special conspiring pattern", then it can be a wave.